# Firewalld Internal zone Rejected

Tags: firewalld

I'm trying a simple firewalld setup on ubuntu/jammy64 as follows with

```
Source (K1) ------ (fw int) | Firewall (FW1) | (fw ext) ------ Destination (K2)
```

```
┌──(vagrant㉿k1)-[~]
└─$ ip -4 a show eth1
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.16.10.51/24 brd 172.16.10.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
┌──(vagrant㉿k1)-[~]
└─$ ip r
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15
172.16.10.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.10.51
172.16.20.0/24 via 172.16.10.10 dev eth1
----------

vagrant@firewall:~$ ip -4 a show enp0s8
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.16.10.10/24 brd 172.16.10.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
vagrant@firewall:~$ ip -4 a show enp0s9
4: enp0s9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.16.20.10/24 brd 172.16.20.255 scope global enp0s9
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

vagrant@firewall:~$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
----------
┌──(vagrant㉿k2)-[~]
└─$  ip -4 a show eth1
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.16.20.51/24 brd 172.16.20.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
┌──(vagrant㉿k2)-[~]
└─$ ip r
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15
172.16.10.0/24 via 172.16.20.10 dev eth1
172.16.20.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.20.51
```

I tried various combinations of adding interfaces, and source addresses to the `Internal` zone and even with a rich rule allowing traffic, k1 can't connect to k2, and the debug log shows a reject message.

```
vagrant@firewall:~$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all  --zone=internal
internal (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp0s8
  sources: 172.16.10.51/32
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
    rule protocol value="icmp" accept
    rule family="ipv4" source address="172.16.10.0/24" port port="5201" protocol="tcp" log prefix="iperf" level="debug" accept
```

```
Jun 30 02:18:13 firewall kernel: "filter_FWD_internal_REJECT: "IN=enp0s8 OUT=enp0s9 MAC=08:00:27:d0:db:54:08:00:27:35:72:b5:08:00 SRC=172.16.10.51 DST=172.16.20.51 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=2173 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=43642 DPT=5201 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

When I add both interfaces to the Internal zone connectivity works fine but not when one of the interfaces is not part of the zone.

Could someone share pointers on where to look next?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When I made a github issue based on this question and my own problem I was directed to make a policy object.

The relevant blog post is here:
https://firewalld.org/2020/09/policy-objects-introduction

Following the directions to create a policy solved my problem. I hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/422847)